# (Jquery) Search Filter bar show and hide

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need add the functionality to show and hide the Search Filter bar

I tried use (example):

```
 setTimeout(showFilter,5000);

 function showFilter(){
    alert('showFilter');

    $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filter = true;
    $('#workList').listview('refresh');

    setTimeout(hideFilter,1500);
 }

 function hideFilter(){
   alert('hideFilter');

   $.mobile.listview.prototype.options.filter = false;
   $('#workList').listview('refresh');
 }
```

But not working, can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with a simple `.hide()` on the searchfilter's container div. The following code will hide every searchfilter textbox on the page, so if you want to hide a certain subset, you'll have to narrow it down to particular parts of your DOM.

```
$(".ui-input-search").hide();
```

Use `.show()` to bring it back up. Alternately, use `.toggle()` to switch back and forth between hidden and visible.

(Note: Any text that has been typed into the search box will still apply, even if the search box is hidden.)